# Using systemd-networkd inside a Podman container

Tags: debian, docker, systemd, podman, systemd-networkd

The end goal is to have a macvlan interface set up within a Podman container. I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM docker.io/library/debian:bookworm-slim
RUN apt-get --yes install systemd
RUN systemctl set-default multi-user.target
CMD ["/lib/systemd/systemd"]
```

If I then run this in privileged mode (detached) and attach a shell to the running container (as root), I can set up a macvlan interface called `macvlan1` on the default tap interface using `iproute2`:

```
# apt install iproute2
# ip link add macvlan1 link tap0 type macvlan mode bridge
```

However, I want to avoid this, and I think it should be possible using `systemd-networkd`, but I'm not having much luck.  I've tried the following `.network` and `.netdev` files (which I have tested to work on my host machine):

```
### 99-test.network
[Match]
Name=tap0

[Network]
MACVLAN=macvlan1
```

```
### 99-test.netdev
[Match]
# Empty

[NetDev]
Name=macvlan1
Kind=macvlan

[MACVLAN]
Mode=bridge
```

I update my Dockerfile like so:

```
FROM docker.io/library/debian:bookworm-slim
COPY 99-test.network /lib/systemd/network
COPY 99-test.netdev /lib/systemd/network
RUN apt-get --yes install systemd
RUN systemctl set-default multi-user.target
RUN systemctl enable systemd-networkd
CMD ["/lib/systemd/systemd"]
```

But when I start up the container, I see no macvlan interface created. If I look at the output of `systemctl status systemd-networkd` there are no logs or error messages suggesting that it's attempted to read the `.network` and `.netdev` files. The only clue I have is that when I run `networkctl` on my host machine, it shows the physical interfaces as `unmanaged` in the `SETUP` column whereas in the container, it shows all interfaces as `pending` (including for a manually-created macvlan interface).

Is what I'm trying to do possible with systemd in Podman? If not, why not?